# My output is not showing up in COBOL

Tags: cobol

I am having a bit of a problem with my COBOL homework again. I think everything is how it is suppose to be, but for some reason I cannot get any output data when I run my program. All it does is show blank lines like someone just hit the enter key over and over. It really sucks cause I can't see if I am right or wrong. Here is my code:

```
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS      PIC X(3)  VALUE 'YES'.

   01 LINE-COUNT                   PIC 99    VALUE ZEROS.

   01  WS-DATE.
       05  RUN-YEAR                PIC XX.
       05  RUN-MONTH               PIC XX.
       05  RUN-DAY                 PIC XX.
   01  HEADING-LINE-1.
       05                          PIC X(24) VALUE SPACES.
       05                          PIC X(26)
           VALUE 'BASEBALL PLAYER STATISTICS'.
       05                          PIC X(12) VALUE SPACES.
       05  HL-1-DATE.
           10  MONTH-2             PIC XX.
           10                      PIC X      VALUE '/'.
           10  DAY-2               PIC XX.
           10                      PIC X      VALUE '/'.
           10  YEAR-2              PIC XX.
       05                          PIC X(6)   VALUE SPACES.
       05  PAGE-1                  PIC X(4)   VALUE 'PAGE'.

   01  HEADING-LINE-2.
       05                          PIC X(6)   VALUE 'LEAGUE'.
       05                          PIC X(3)   VALUE SPACES.
       05                          PIC X(4)   VALUE 'TEAM'.
       05                          PIC X(5)   VALUE SPACES.
       05                          PIC X(4)   VALUE 'NAME'.
       05                          PIC X(10)  VALUE SPACES.
       05                          PIC X(4)   VALUE 'HITS'.
       05                          PIC X(6)   VALUE SPACES.
       05                          PIC X(7)   VALUE 'AT BATS'.
   01  DETAIL-LINE.
       05 BLANK-A-OUT              PIC X      VALUE SPACES.
       05 DL-LEAGUE                PIC XX.
       05 BLANK-B-OUT              PIC X(3)   VALUE SPACES.
       05 DL-TEAM                  PIC X(3).
       05 BLANK-C-OUT              PIC X(3)   VALUE SPACES.
       05 DL-NAME                  PIC X(10).
       05 BLANK-D-OUT              PIC X(3)   VALUE SPACES.
       05 DL-HITS                  PIC ZZ9.
       05 BLANK-E-OUT              PIC X(3)   VALUE SPACES.
       05 DL-AT-BATS               PIC ZZ9.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   100-MAIN.
       OPEN INPUT BASEBALL-FILE-IN
       OPEN OUTPUT BASEBALL-FILE-OUT

       ACCEPT WS-DATE FROM DATE
       MOVE RUN-MONTH TO MONTH-2
       MOVE RUN-DAY TO DAY-2
       MOVE RUN-YEAR TO YEAR-2
       WRITE BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT

       PERFORM UNTIL ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS = 'NO '
           READ BASEBALL-FILE-IN
               AT END
                   MOVE 'NO ' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS
               NOT AT END
                   PERFORM 200-PROCESS-ONE-RECORD
           END-READ
       END-PERFORM

       CLOSE BASEBALL-FILE-IN
       CLOSE BASEBALL-FILE-OUT
       STOP RUN.


   200-PROCESS-ONE-RECORD.
       MOVE LEAGUE-IN TO DL-LEAGUE
       MOVE SPACES TO BLANK-A-OUT
       MOVE TEAM-IN TO DL-TEAM
       MOVE SPACES TO BLANK-B-OUT
       MOVE NAME-IN TO DL-NAME
       MOVE SPACES TO BLANK-C-OUT
       MOVE HITS-IN TO DL-HITS
       MOVE SPACES TO BLANK-D-OUT
       MOVE AT-BATS-IN TO DL-AT-BATS
       MOVE SPACES TO BLANK-E-OUT
       WRITE BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT
           AFTER ADVANCING 2 LINES.

   300-LINE.
       IF  LINE-COUNT >= 50
           PERFORM 400-NEXT-PAGE
       END-IF
       WRITE BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT
           AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE
       ADD 1 TO LINE-COUNT.

   400-NEXT-PAGE.
       WRITE BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT
           AFTER ADVANCING PAGE
       MOVE ZEROS TO LINE-COUNT.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never moving the data you read from BASEBALL-2.SEQ into the record used to write BASEBALL-2.RPT.

You can do something like

```
* WRITE THE HEADER INFO
MOVE HEADING-LINE-1 TO BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT 
WRITE BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT
```

Or

```
WRITE BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT FROM HEADING-LINE-1
```

Similarly you can write the details line

```
* WRITE THE DETAIL
MOVE DETAIL-LINE TO BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT 
WRITE BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT
```

Answer (score 3):

Several different patterns may be used when coding COBOL I/O operations. I see two
distinct patterns in your program.

**Pattern 1:**

Define I/O record layouts under the FD entry. You have done this for your input file.
BASEBALL-RECORD-IN serves as both a file I/O buffer and a full record description.

**Pattern 2:**

Define a dummy FD record buffer then create additional detail record definitions under Working Storage.
You did this for your output record. BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT is just an I/O buffer and
the detail record layouts are defend under Working Strorage using three different record
layouts: HEADING-LINE-1, HEADING-LINE-1 and DETAIL-LINE.

**What is the difference?**

The primary differences relate to when each of these records becomes addressable and how you read/write data.

When using Pattern 1, only a single record buffer is allocated. This is the record
associated with the file's FD clause. In your case this is the 36 byte BASEBALL-RECORD-IN
record. This buffer may not be addressable until after the file it is associated with has been OPENed. Attempting
to access this record buffer (by explicitly initializing it, moving spaces to it or any other reference) would
cause a run-time error (crash and burn). After the open and READ, data are available in the record 
buffer associated with the FD. Since this FD has a defined record structure, you may
reference any of the fields in it (e.g. NAME-IN) immediately after issuing a READ statement.

When using Pattern 2, Separate record structures are declared in Working Storage. Here the records
HEADING-LINE-1, HEADING-LINE-2 and DETAIL-LINE are all addressable
when the program starts running - even though the output record buffer BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT (associated
with the FD) will not be addressable until after the output file has been opened. The thing to remember here
is that there is no "automatic" connection between the record buffer BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT and the Working
storage records HEADING-LINE-1, HEADING-LINE-2 and DETAIL-LINE - you have to explicitly MOVE the data from Working
Storage to the record buffer using something like:

```
 MOVE HEADING-LINE-1 TO BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT
 WRITE BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT
```

before each and every WRITE operation. Alternatively you could write from the Working Storage record as in:

```
 WRITE BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT FROM HEADING-LINE-1
```

This is just a sugar coated way of doing the MOVE/WRITE illustrated above.

This explanation should make it clear to you why the READ puts data directly into a fully 
fielded record structure for reference, but WRITE requires an additional MOVE of some sort.

These are two I/O patterns available in COBOL. As you learn more about the language quite a few
additional patterns should come to light as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I touched Cobol but you are probably missing updating BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move HEADING-LINE-1, HEADING-LINE-2, and DETAIL-LINE to BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT before you WRITE BASEBALL-RECORD-OUT.

Answer (score 0):

I see there are two paragraphs which are not executed in the code starting 300- and 400- as they are not performed and are below the stop run. There may be i-o-control entries omitted for the output to the file and the output appears to be written to a file and not to a display screen or printer. This would depend any default settings or those of any external assignments or redirects.